# how to change the background color of padding in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, colors, background

my plot below has padding between subplots or padding to the top/bottom or left/right depending on size of the app window.  I'm totally happy with the spacing and layout management happening here, and want to keep the flexibility as the number of plots grows or shrinks (or the app window resizes) to have things sized dynamically.  however, I want the background color of this padding to be the same gray background as the app rather than white.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)



ui <- dashboardPage(
    
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    
    body = dashboardBody(
        
        fluidRow(
            plotOutput("test",  width = '100%'), align="center"
        )
    )
)



server <- function(input, output) {

    #generate some dummy data with a random number of plots to show
    set.seed(NULL)
    numPlots <- sample(1:5, 1)
    plot <- sort(rep(seq(1:numPlots), 10))
    d <- data.frame(A = runif(10*numPlots, 0, 10), B = runif(10*numPlots, 0, 10), C = plot)
    
    
    
    matchingGray <- rgb(236/255, 240/255, 245/255)  #best guess using screenshot and then dropper in another tool
    
    g <- list()
    for (p in 1:numPlots)
    {
        g[[p]] <- ggcorrplot(corr = cor(d %>% filter(C == p) %>% select(A,B))) +
            theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = matchingGray, linetype = "blank"))
    }
    
    
    
    output$test <- renderPlot({
        
        gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = g, ncol = length(g))
        
    })
}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

disregard the silly data giving nonsense correlations, this is just a simple place holder to get at the heart of the issue.  having a variable number of subplots is key though... try running the app multiple times to see the implications on the padding.  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question can be solved on the plotting methods instead from the shiny side. Use `cowplot::ggdraw` to solve the problem:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(cowplot)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
            plotOutput("test",  width = '100%'), align="center"
        )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
    #generate some dummy data with a random number of plots to show
    set.seed(NULL)
    numPlots <- sample(1:5, 1)
    plot <- sort(rep(seq(1:numPlots), 10))
    d <- data.frame(A = runif(10*numPlots, 0, 10), B = runif(10*numPlots, 0, 10), C = plot)
    matchingGray <- rgb(236/255, 240/255, 245/255)  #best guess using screenshot and then dropper in another tool
    
    g <- list()
    for (p in 1:numPlots) {
        g[[p]] <- ggcorrplot(corr = cor(d %>% filter(C == p) %>% select(A,B))) +
            theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = matchingGray, linetype = "blank"))
    }
    output$test <- renderPlot({
        cowplot::ggdraw(gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = g, ncol = length(g), bg = "wheat1")) +
            theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill="#ecf0f5", color = NA))
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thank you!!!  NA still left a white box but easy fix by setting color also to my matching gray